# Rails: How to implement in place editing without using Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

This may be too general a question, but I am trying to implement a in place editing feature on the index page. This is for my Rails 4 project. The gem Best_In_Place seems to be able to do what I want but I have issue implementing it (due to tutorials being outdated and seems to be meant for Rails 3.

What I am trying to achieve is this:

1. This is a Wedding Portal which allows the User to assign guests to
   different tables
2. After the User adds Guests information through
   the New view, all the guests will be displayed on the Index view.
3. The User can then edit the guest information (i.e. name, table no.)
   directly from the index page. This is sort of like a spreadsheet.

There are many questions which points to the Best_In_Place gem, somehow that does not work for me. So my question is whether it is possible to use a front end framework like AngularJS or BackboneJS to implement this? If yes, are there any tutorials or resources which is relevant to this?